# How do i find the text value of a id element?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to disable the submit button until the user_name and email check has been returned this works, but i dont want it to continue and reveal the submit button if there are errors. i.e. username/email already exists!

I have been trying to retrieve my error value from id="livesearchEmail" within my form. If its clear i.e. no errors then i want the button to become active! What I have looks straight forward enough but it does not work! What am i missing?

I have been trying all day to get a value returned from #livesearchEmail but to no avail.

Any help or points in the right direction will be gratefully accepted!

```
<div id="livesearchEmail" class="livesearchEmail"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">  
    $(document).ready(function() {    
        $('input[id="registerButton"]').attr('disabled','disabled');
        $('input[type="text"]').keyup(function() {
        if ($('#user_name').val() != "" && $('#email').val() != "") {
            if ($("#livesearchEmail") == ''){
                $('input[id="registerButton"]').removeAttr('disabled');
            }
        }
        });        
    });​​
</script>
```

Comment: It would help a lot if you could share a snippet of your HTML, and identify the jQuery (or Zeptos) version you are using.

Comment: You are comparing an object with an empty string, and it will always be false, but on the line just above your doing the same, but the right way, why ??? All you really have to do is : `if (!$("#livesearchEmail").length){..do your thing..}`

Comment: @user1372764 You wanted to read the contents of the block #livesearchEmail . Is that correct?. Then use the .text() function like i have mentioned. Otherwise be more specific with your question?.

Answer (score 0):

Try using
`$("#livesearchEmail").text();`

---

**Edit - added code**

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
     $('input[id="registerButton"]').attr('disabled','disabled');
     $('input[type="text"]').keyup(function() {
        if($('#user_name').val() != "" && $('#email').val() != ""){
            if ($("#livesearchEmail").text() == ""){
                $('input[id="registerButton"]').removeAttr('disabled');
            }
        }
     });  
 });
```

Comment: He has told "I have been trying to retrieve my error value from id="livesearchEmail" within my form"  . I'm thinking that erorr message is in that Div. and nobody would use  Id's for an input email box.

Comment: I would like to know 'why' i got down voted?.  if the user's requirement is to get the content from the  selector , he should be using .text()

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the data that you are trying to get at is in a DOM element (like a <div>) and not a form element you could just do:
`if ($("#livesearchEmail")[0].innerHTML === '')`

or if want to keep it jQuery I think you can use the text() function:
`if ($("#livesearchEmail").text() === '')`

Also, notice that I'm using a triple equals to prevent falsey evaluation.

Comment: What kind of false evaluation? `$("#livesearchEmail").text()` will always return a string and even `("false" == "")` will return `false`

Answer (score 0):

[**jQuery ID Selector (“#id”)**](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/)

Because ID's are unique you don't need to construct a special selector with tag and all the stuff. For example you can simply convert this: `$('input[id="registerButton"]')` to this: `$("#registerButton")`.

I'm not quite sure why you want to check if no error returned because the button will never get active if you check that. But however under your requirements this jQuery code will work for you:

```
$(document).ready(function() {    
    $("#registerButton").attr('disabled','disabled');
    $('input[type="text"]').keyup(function() {
    if ($('#user_name').val() && $('#email').val() && (!$("#livesearchEmail").length || !$("#livesearchEmail").text())) {
        $("#registerButton").removeAttr('disabled');
    }
    });        
});
```